# idle time out always should be greater than session time out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, state-management

I have a project in asp.net c#.I am not using forms authentication.I have simple login page.When user successfully login  user redirect to dashboard and session["user"] also generated.But the problem is when  user do not use website for 20 minutes or greater than 20 minutes  and when  user came back try to use it.session is expired.User redirected to again login page.
I am using also following script in web.config file

```
<sessionState timeout = "500" mode = "InProc" />
```

Is this is because idle time out or not because my idle time out is 20 minuter.
IS idle time out  always should be greater than  session time out?I want session alive 8 to 9 hours or maximum or user do not press logout  button

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the defaullt 20, from the configuration. But you can change this timing from your IIS.

Check it in IIS.
Open the IIS, click on the Application Pools, Select the Application pool for your application.

> Right Click --> Select Properties

In the

> Performance tab

Set the idle timeout as your desired minutes for "shutdown worker processes after being idle for ..... minutes".

> Restart IIS after that.

Comment: when i will change the idle time out through IIS.Session will  not be  expired?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the session time out to anything greater than 1 hour will result in excessive memory being held in memory, an IIS holds all session memory for the duration of the session.Imagine a time out value of 5 hours on a high traffic site,holding session data for thousands of users' sessions.

To resolve this issue, we need to automatically refresh the web page in the application inorder to create a postback.This can be done with a **meta-refresh** tag.

Start by adding the following tag to your master page:

```
<IFRAME ID="KeepAliveFrame" src="KeepSessionAlive.aspx" frameBorder="0" width="0" height="0" runat="server"></IFRAME>
```

Next, create a new page named KeepSessionAlive.aspx. In the head section of the page, add the following lines:

```
<meta id="MetaRefresh" http-equiv="refresh" content="21600;url=KeepSessionAlive.aspx" runat="server" />
<script language="javascript">
window.status = "<%=WindowStatusText%>";
</script>
```

The key to this line is the content value. By default, we set the value to 21600 seconds, which is equal to 6 hours. However, we will be setting the value ourselves in the Page_Load of the web application for this page, so this default value can be ignored.

Add the following code to the Page_Load of KeepSessionAlive.aspx.cs:

```
    protected string WindowStatusText = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Refresh this page 60 seconds before session timeout, effectively resetting the session timeout counter.
            MetaRefresh.Attributes["content"] = Convert.ToString((Session.Timeout * 60) - 60) + ";url=KeepSessionAlive.aspx?q=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;

            WindowStatusText = "Last refresh " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        }
    }
```

The final important step is to change your web.config session timeout value to be a value less than that of IIS's possible timeout values. If your value is greater than IIS's, your auto-refresh will never occur since IIS would have already reset your session state before the refresh timer activates. Choosing a value such as 10 minutes appears to work well. Remember, even though the session timeout value is 10 minutes, your auto-refresh method combined with sliding expiration, will keep the session alive.

Comment: I am not using form authentication